# How do I combine 3 for loop?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have 3 for each statements which are looping through statutes in xml document (**aobjXMLCaseDoc**) and then checking to see if those statutes match the following statutes 260C.405, 518.131, 518B.01, 609.748, 629.75

I would like to combine these 3 for each into one for each statement.
How do I do that?

**XML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Charge>
    <ChargeHistory ChargeHistoryID="387">
        <Statute>
            <StatuteNumber>609.352.2a(2)</StatuteNumber>
        </Statute>
    </ChargeHistory>
    <ChargeHistory ChargeHistoryID="398">
        <Statute>
            <StatuteNumber>609.352.2a(2)</StatuteNumber>
        </Statute>
    </ChargeHistory>
    <ChargeHistory ChargeHistoryID="517">
        <Statute>
            <StatuteNumber>609.352.2a(2)</StatuteNumber>
        </Statute>
    </ChargeHistory>
    <Deleted>false</Deleted>
</Charge>
```

**VB Code**

```vb
'Check if statute has 8 characters
    For Each objXMLStatuteNode In aobjXMLCaseDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Case/Charge/ChargeHistory/Statute/StatuteNumber")
        If objXMLStatuteNode.InnerText.Length >= 8 Then
            strStatuteEightDigits = objXMLStatuteNode.InnerText.Substring(0, 8)
            Select Case strStatuteEightDigits
                Case "260C.405"
                    blnNotSpecifiedStatute = False
                Case Else
                    blnNotSpecifiedStatute = True
            End Select
        End If
    Next

    'Check if statute has 7 characters 
    For Each objXMLStatuteNode In aobjXMLCaseDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Case/Charge/ChargeHistory/Statute/StatuteNumber")
        If objXMLStatuteNode.InnerText.Length >= 7 Then
            strStatuteSevenDigits = objXMLStatuteNode.InnerText.Substring(0, 7)
            Select Case strStatuteSevenDigits
                Case "518.131", "518B.01", "609.748"
                    blnNotSpecifiedStatute = False
                Case Else
                    blnNotSpecifiedStatute = True
            End Select
        End If
    Next

    'Check if statute has 6 characters 
    For Each objXMLStatuteNode In aobjXMLCaseDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Case/Charge/ChargeHistory/Statute/StatuteNumber")
        If objXMLStatuteNode.InnerText.Length >= 6 Then
            strStatuteSixDigits = objXMLStatuteNode.InnerText.Substring(0, 6)
            Select Case strStatuteSixDigits
                Case "629.75"
                    blnNotSpecifiedStatute = False
                Case Else
                    blnNotSpecifiedStatute = True
            End Select
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: I don't even think this works as is since the value of blnNotSpecifiedStatute entirely depends on the last check.

Comment: This is why I asked for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your code seems to be doing is checking to see if any of the statute numbers **begin** with one of the five strings ("260C.405", "518.131", "518B.01", "609.748", "629.75"). You can use `StartsWith` to do that.

You can use `Any` to check if any of the statute numbers meet some test, and that test can also use `Any` to see if the statute number starts with any of a list of strings. The whole thing can be done in a single statement.

The example XML you provide starts with `<Charge>`, but your code seems to assume that the `<Charge>` elements exist within a `<Case>` element. To be consistent, I have removed `<Case>` from the code. You will need to put it back (immediately before `<Charge>`) if it is needed.

Note that your code (and mine below) checks for any statute number beginning with "629.75", so "629.751" would be considered a match. It's possible that you want to check for statute numbers beginning with "629.75." rather than "629.75"

```
Private statutes As New List(Of String) From {"260C.405", "518.131", "518B.01", "609.748", "629.75"}
Private objXML As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                              <Charge>
                                  <ChargeHistory ChargeHistoryID="387">
                                      <Statute>
                                          <StatuteNumber>609.352.2a(2)</StatuteNumber>
                                      </Statute>
                                  </ChargeHistory>
                                  <ChargeHistory ChargeHistoryID="398">
                                      <Statute>
                                          <StatuteNumber>609.352.2a(2)</StatuteNumber>
                                      </Statute>
                                  </ChargeHistory>
                                  <ChargeHistory ChargeHistoryID="517">
                                      <Statute>
                                          <StatuteNumber>609.352.2a(2)</StatuteNumber>
                                      </Statute>
                                  </ChargeHistory>
                                  <Deleted>false</Deleted>
                              </Charge>

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim blnNotSpecifiedStatute As Boolean
    blnNotSpecifiedStatute = Not objXML.<Charge>.<ChargeHistory>.<Statute>.<StatuteNumber>.Any(Function(n) statutes.Any(Function(s) n.Value.StartsWith(s)))
    'Do something with blnNotSpecifiedStatute 
End Sub
```

Comment: Does that mean I do not need to loop through the Case/Charge/ChargeHistory/Statute/StatuteNumber to find the statute number? What I am trying to do is use the xml document and look up the statutes to see if any in xml document match these statutes 260C.405, 518.131, 518B.01, 609.748, 629.75. If any matches, then I want to set blnNotSpecifiedStatute to False, if no matches the blnNotSpecifiedStatute is set to true.

Comment: The code in my answer causes a loop to be performed, it just does it all in one statement. `objXML.<Charge>.<ChargeHistory>.<Statute>.<StatuteNumber>.Any(Function(n).....)` will process every <StatuteNumber> element. The <StatuteNumber> element becomes the `n` in `Function(n)`.

Comment: I did make some changes to your example and now my code is working. Since I do not want to keep losing points, I will not add my code here. I risk being banned!

Answer (score 1):

Use If-ElseIf:

```
For Each objXMLStatuteNode In aobjXMLCaseDoc.DocumentElement....

    If objXMLStatuteNode.InnerText.Length >= 8 Then  
       ''' Checks for 8 or more chars
       ....                     
    ElseIf objXMLStatuteNode.InnerText.Length = 7 Then  
       ''' Checks for 7 Chars
       .... 
    ElseIf objXMLStatuteNode.InnerText.Length = 6 Then   
       ''' Checks for 6 chars
       ....
    Else
       ''' For Less than 6 chars
    End If

Next
```

Also I think you logic might need a bit of tweaking because 8 is >= 8, but it is also >= 7 and is also >= 6.